# After Chage Rails version conflict occured .Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my new project(ruby-2.5), I accidentally installed version of rails(5.2.2). I was supposed to install rails(5.1.0). So I tried to downgraded version and changed gem file to 5.1.0. After `bundle install` conflict occurred. How can I change to the rails version 5.1.0 safely.

**What I have done:**

1. bundle exec gem uninstall rails -v 5.2.2
2. change gem file to gem 'rails', '5.1.0'
3. bundle install
4. conflict occurred.

as,

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
activesupport (= 5.2.2)

In Gemfile:
sass-rails (~> 5.0) was resolved to 5.0.7, which depends on
sprockets-rails (< 4.0, >= 2.0) was resolved to 3.2.1, which depends 
on
actionpack (>= 4.0) was resolved to 5.2.2, which depends on
      activesupport (= 5.2.2)

rails (= 5.1.0) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
activesupport (= 5.1.0)

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, 
using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

5. followed the message and bundle update. But still error got occurred.

**Gem file**

```
    gem 'rails', '5.1.0'

    gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.4.4', '< 0.6.0'

    gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'

    gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'

    gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'

    gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

    group :development, :test do

      gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]

    end

    group :development do

      gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'

      gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'

      gem 'spring'

      gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'

    end
```

Comment: Remove Gemfile.lock and rerun `bundle install`

Comment: Thanks for reply. i did "rm Gemfile.lock", then "bundle install"
but still same.

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 5.1.0) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
      bundler (< 2.0, >= 1.3.0)

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (2.0.1)
This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?

Could not find gem 'bundler (< 2.0, >= 1.3.0)', which is required by gem 'rails (= 5.1.0)', in any of the sources.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you have an additional issue due to Bundler 2.0 which was just released a few days ago (https://bundler.io/blog/2019/01/04/an-update-on-the-bundler-2-release.html).

```
# Make sure Gemfile.lock is removed
$ rm Gemfile.lock

# Remove Bundler v 2.0
$ gem uninstall bundler

# Install pre-2.0 Bundler 
$ gem install bundler -v '1.17.3'

# Finally, you should be able to
$ bundle
```

Comment: Thanks for reply claasz!! It worked. But, i have now another problem related to this. i suppose i should not ask about new problem in this place.Anyway thanks for your help.