# After bundle install "rails s" command is not working. cannot load such file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I had a problem with downgrade rails version in my new project([After Chage Rails version conflict occured .Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069251/after-chage-rails-version-conflict-occured-bundler-could-not-find-compatible-ve)).

Now i think project's rails version is uninstalled & changed to 5.1.0. However "bin/rails s"command is not working and can't launching rails server.

**1: Before changing rails version 5.2.2 to 5.1.0  "bin/rails s" command 
worked.**

**2: "bin/rails -v" gives Rails 5.1.0**

**3: "bin/rails s" gives error below.**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
30: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
29: from 
/Users/username/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport- 
5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
28: from 
/Users/username/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport- 
5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
27: from 
/Users/username/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport- 
5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
26: from 
/Users/username/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap- 
1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in 
`require'
.
.
.
.
58:in `load_dependency'
 1: from /Users/username/project
/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport- 
5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
/Users/username/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap- 
1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in 
`require': cannot load such file -- active_storage/engine 
(LoadError)



gemfile

ruby '2.5.1'

gem 'rails', '5.1.0'
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.4.4', '< 0.6.0'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
gem 'spring'
gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

application.rb

require "rails"
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"

require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "action_cable/engine"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Project
 class Application < Rails::Application
  # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails 
  version.
  config.load_defaults 5.2

  # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those 
  specified here.
  # Application configuration can go into files in config/initializers
  # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded after 
  loading
  # the framework and any gems in your application.

  # Don't generate system test files.
  config.generators.system_tests = nil
 end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried `bundle exec rails s`?

Comment: Hi thanks for reply yoones. yes i have. 
same.

Comment: `ActiveStorage` was introduced in Rails 5.2, so you have to manually include this in your Gemfile after downgrarde to 5.1.

Comment: What i done is 
By mistake i made new rails project(5.2.2) i uninstalled rails 5.2.2 then installed 5.1.0 conflict occured removed gemlock and installed 5.1.0 again. Rails s command is not working now.

Comment: Hi Marek Lipka!! So do i have to add gem file ?

Comment: I would start a new project using `5.1`.

Comment: Yes i think i should start new project again. Thank you so much for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue occurs because rails tries to load active_storage, and you don't have that in version 5.1.

The likely solution would be to remove the line `require "active_storage/engine"` from `config/application.rb` and change `config.load_defaults 5.2` to `config.load_defaults 5.1`

Comment: Hi thanks. i removed require "active_storage/engine" then 
bin/rails s

/Users/username/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:81:in `load_defaults': Unknown version "5.2" (RuntimeError)

Comment: Andrew Thank you so much!!!! i'll start new project again. I think that is quick way.

Comment: @arthur, if you haven't started anew, you should try changing `config.load_defaults 5.2` to `config.load_defaults 5.1` in the aforementioned file

Comment: Hi @Andrew thank you for your advice. I thought that might be the problem, but i just thought making new project is much easier.
Now I made new project and seems ok with it. Thanks again!!!!

Answer (score -1):

Remove :

```
require: false
```

From :

```
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false
```

This will do the trick.